# Can I have parametrized SQLSTATE in exceptions in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, exception, plpgsql

I tend to write my PostgreSQL functions in a way that I always have default exception handler, that adds function name to the exception thrown and re-throws it again.

Example:

```
BEGIN
    RAISE exception SQLSTATE '77777' using message = 'Test exception';
EXCEPTION
    WHEN others THEN
        raise exception 
        using message = 'error_handling_test: ' || sqlstate
        || '/' || sqlerrm;
END;
```

In this case, the SQLSTATE 77777 is not propagated further and exception I catch later has default SQLSTATE P0001.

It is possible to add SQLSTATE also to exception handler raise, but this seems to be limited to hardcoded string. What I would like to get is something like this:

```
DECLARE
    err_code varchar;
BEGIN
    RAISE exception SQLSTATE '77777' using message = 'Test exception';
EXCEPTION
    WHEN others THEN

        err_code:=sqlstate;

        raise exception sqlstate err_code
        using message = 'error_handling_test: ' || sqlstate
        || '/' || sqlerrm;
END;
```

This won't compile.

Comment: Always provide a complete function definition, *including* the header. Even if it's trivial, it makes testing easier. And your Postgres version, of course.

Comment: if you can use a 9.3, then you can use a additional exception fields http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING so you don't need to soil message field.

Comment: @PavelStehule - this is of no use for my use case as I need the sqlstate outside of Postgres, in Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would work like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_err()
RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN
    RAISE exception SQLSTATE '77777' using message = 'Test exception';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN others THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION
      USING ERRCODE = sqlstate
           ,MESSAGE = 'error_handling_test: ' || sqlstate || '/' || sqlerrm;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The value for `SQLSTATE` in `RAISE EXCEPTION SQLSTATE '12345'` cannot be a variable, but must be a literal. [The manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) is not very clear about that.

Provide the error code in the `USING` clause instead.

Note for the casual reader: the [special variables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-EXCEPTION-DIAGNOSTICS) `sqlstate` and `sqlerrm` are only visible in the `EXCEPTION` handler.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for, works as expected.